# Wicket modal window not displaying properly

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to create a modal window for my application, but unfortunately I am unable to do so.

I have a page that extends `WebPage` and I have added a panel that extends `Panel` to it. The page and panel are written separately; that is, in `panel.java` and `page.java`. Now, I have added a modal window to the panel with the help of [this Wicket Examples example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/modal-window) ([source](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?1&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.modal.ModalWindowPage)). But when the page renders, I am seeing — by inspecting element of that page — that the `div` with `wicket:id` of "modal1" has attribute `script="display: none"`. I don't know what to do. Any information will be very helpful to me.

One more thing: are

```
return new ModalContent1Page(ModalWindowPage.this.getPageReference(), modal1);
```

and

```
return new ModalContent1Page(ModalWindowPage.this, modal1);
```

the same?



Edit:

The problem is solved. Actually when I asked the question I did not have the code then. I was following the tutorial of [RoseIndia](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/wicket/modal-panel.shtml), but I was unsuccessful and as I am using wicket 1.3.1 the PageReference class is not available there. So I solve it as:

```
    final ModalWindow modalWindow;
    add(modalWindow = new ModalWindow("modalVideo"));

    modalWindow.setCookieName("modal-video");
    modalWindow.setCssClassName(ModalWindow.CSS_CLASS_GRAY);
    modalWindow.setResizable(false);
    modalWindow.setInitialHeight(215);
    modalWindow.setInitialWidth(215);
    modalWindow.setHeightUnit("px");        

    modalWindow.setPageCreator(new ModalWindow.PageCreator() {
        public Page createPage() {
            return new PlayVideo(ItemViewPanel.this.getPage(), modalWindow, itemId);
        }
    });

    AjaxLink showModalLink;
    add(showModalLink = new AjaxLink("showModal") {
        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    modalWindow.show(target);
        }
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add some bits of code to your question? I'd try to figure out a solution for you but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second question: no, those two lines of code are not the same. `ModalWindowPage.this` is the page itself, so its type is `ModalWindowPage`. `getPageReference()`, on the other hand, returns a `PageReference`, which is not in the same hierarchy.